# How to remove/hide Paypal logo from Card.io Phonegap iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, paypal, card.io

I have successfully integrated the Card.io plugin for Phonegap in Android and iOS.

My client does not want the Paypal logo to be displayed on the top right of the scanning screen. Is there a way to hide it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current PhoneGap plugin implementation doesn't have this functionality implemented, however it very simple to add it, just fork the plugin and modify it to use card.io logo instead of PayPal.

For iOS https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/blob/master/CardIO/CardIOPaymentViewController.h#L92

For Android http://card-io.github.io/card.io-Android-SDK/io/card/payment/CardIOActivity.html#EXTRA_USE_CARDIO_LOGO

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am in the right track, thanks Romk1n. I was able to set the value of EXTRA_USE_CARDIO_LOGO to false in CardIOMain.java to remove the paypal logo. Android is done, but I'm not very good with Objective C.. I know I just have to change value of 'useCardIOLogo' from NO to YES. But I don't know where or how to do that. Could you please mention the steps for doing that in iOS?

Comment: Just call self.paymentViewController.useCardIOLogo = YES; after https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK-PhoneGap/blob/master/CardIOPGPlugin.m#L32

Comment: Great! The answer is now complete.. :) It will be nice to know if there was a way to remove the logos completely. As if now, the card.io logo is shown instead of Paypal.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah , is possible HIDE logo paypal and logo Card IO in Android native, But its a work Hard.

You need open Jar card.io, after that you need decompiler code, after that with .class files

you need Assembler Editor to in Byte code instruction of Machine you can Remove booth images

and nothing is showed, you cannot remove keyboard, but you can put a black screen above that, in link , you have card-io-modified.jar , with this jar you remove that things

get lib here : https://github.com/luizfelipetx/CardIO-Modified

=)

Comment: This is a clever solution, and I applaud your hard work. However, out of respect for the fact that card.io is offered free to the world, I'd ask that you take down the repo, and that folks in general not do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For Native IOS

```
 CardIOPaymentViewController *scanViewController = [[CardIOPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPaymentDelegate:self];


 scanViewController.hideCardIOLogo=YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin: [Card.IO](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.keepe.cardio)

It has property called "hideLogo": true

Answer (score 0):

On line 81 of CardIOCordovaPlugin.m, you can change the line of code

```
paymentViewController.hideCardIOLogo = YES;
```